# Преобразовать в треугольную матрицу

Tags: c++, матрицы, vector

помогите преобразовать матрицу в верхнюю треугольную. Я заполняю циклом всю матрицу, и хочу потом элементы под главной диагональю приравнять к нулю, но не могу додумать как это сделать. Треугольник должен быть сверху слева.

```
int n;
    cout << "Введите число n:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    cout << "исход:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vector<int> save;
        for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++)
        {
            save.push_back(rand() % 10);
        }
        vec.push_back(save);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоп-стоп. *Преобразовать* или *создать*?

Преобразовать - это что-то типа метода Гаусса или LU-разложения, это отдельный сложный вопрос.

А создать ее изначально такой - куда проще:

```
cin >> n;
vector<vector<int>> vec(n, vector<int>(n));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n-i; j++)
        vec[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

Это для треугольника "*сверху слева*", над побочной диагональю.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        vec[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

Это - для треугольника "*над главной диагональю*".

Из-за того, что вы путаетесь в терминологии и не в состоянии внятно и непротиворечиво сформулировать задачу, приходится давать массу решений... :(

Кстати, заметьте - не нужны никакие `push_back` и временные векторы, даже не нужно ничего обнулять - если создать матрицу сразу:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec(n, vector<int>(n));
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Да без проблем, если ответ устраивает - птичка принятия ответа слева к вашим услугам :) Только на будущее - старайтесь формулировать вопросы предельно точно и информативно, а то при неточном ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Введите число n:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    cout << "исход:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vector<int> save;
        for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++)
        {
            save.push_back(rand() % 10);
        }
        vec.push_back(save);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = n+1 - i; j < n+1; j++)
        {
            vec[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```